# Screen sharing problem in all common application in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, when I try to share my screen with any usual app like Skype, Google meeting, Zoom, Telegram the only screen that I'm able to share is black screen, It shows the other open app screen but when I share them it will be freeze

Comment: In all these application we have option name 'share screen' or 'present'. the option for sharing your screen

Comment: Share screen with what? Another computer? A mobile phone? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit may be Wayland, the new display manager that replaces Xorg. Both on a new install and on an install or upgrade, the system is moved to Wayland. Lacking further information, it is therefore very likely that you are running Wayland with 22.04.

It has all kinds of security mechanisms, breaking also traditional screen sharing. Applications have to be adapted to allow for this functionality in Wayland.

If you cannot move to applications that properly run on Wayland, you can move back to Xorg. On the login-screen, before entering your password, select the session "Ubuntu on Xorg" using the cog at the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: I ran echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE command and it returns X11, It seems I'm not using Wayland

Comment: This information belongs to your question. Then, it could be related o your graphics information

Answer (score 1):

I was resolved by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` and changing the value from `Default` to `Enabled`.

then

Search for the **file.conf** in **/etc/gdm3/** in my case, Ubuntu 22.04, it's **custom.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

then `reboot`

"*uncommenting that line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland* "

Comment: Please do not copy and paste identical answers to different questions on AU. The system has detected this *exact* answer given to 3 slightly different questions.